# PHP sort and linux sort command differ

Tags: php, sorting

I am attempting to sort files using first PHP's built-in sort. However, the file size got too large to handle effectively in PHP (it is 8gb). So I turned to the Linux sort module. The problem is that it is not sorting it in the same order as PHP (there is a diff type program that needs the sorted output). For example sort produces the following output:

```
aacoinc
aa-power 
aarondesigninc
```

Whereas PHP produces the expected:

```
aa-power 
aacoinc
aarondesigninc
```

THe sort command I am using is:

```
sort -k1,1 infile > outfile
```

I have been through the sort documentation but nothing seems to help me there. If sort just doesn't operate this way, can anyone point me to another solution?

Comment: Setting LC_ALL=C should fix this, as mentioned in the WARNING section of the linux sort man page. (I have no idea how it can default to - being somewhere between c and r)

Comment: Thanks. Literally just figured that out and was coming on to post it.

Comment: @mlewis54 Please resolve this abandoned page by posting an informative answer.  This way new duplicates can be closed with this older page.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by Wooble in the comments, the trick to making this work is using the LC_ALL=C will work. Example

```
sort LC_ALL=C -k1,1 infile > outfile
```